# Ocaml - Accessing components in an array of records

Tags: arrays, ocaml, record

I have a array of record type tt - originally with more components ;-) - and like to change its values within a for loop:

```
type tt={mutable x: int};;
let f0={x= -1};;
let max=10;;
let ff=Array.create max f0;;
for i=0 to max-1 do ff.(i).x <- i;done;;
```

Nevertheless, all fields of ff have the value 9 instead of having values from 0 to 9. Is ff.(i).x correct? I also tried

```
for i=0 to max-1 do f0.x <- i;ff.(i) <- f0;done;;
```

but with the same result... (I'm using OCaml version 4.00.1)
What is wrong? I would be happy if somebody could give me a hint!

Answer (score 9):

This is a classic mistake that beginners do with `Array.create` and mutable state. I have explained it in detail [there](http://yquem.inria.fr/~protzenk/caml-faq/doku.php?id=array_make_bug). The summary is that `Array.create n foo` does not create copies of `foo` (how could it?), it creates an array of cases all pointing to the same `foo`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that all cells of the `ff` array contain the *same* element, namely `f0`. You need to create a fresh element of type `tt` for each cell.
This is a way to do so:

```
type tt={mutable x: int};;
let max=10;;
let ff=Array.init max (fun i -> {x= i});;
```

Now you can modify a cell without affecting the other cells.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that, since the record is mutable, it is stored *by reference* and not *by value* as you would expect from a non mutable data type (as an integer) so when you do

```
let ff=Array.create 10 f0;;
```

you are actually storing 10 references to the same record. And then each iteration of

```
for i=0 to max-1 do ff.(i).x <- i;done;;
```

just updates the same reference multiple times, so since last iteration is with `i = 9` then the only real record contained in the array gets that value.

What you need to do is to create 10 different record such with:

```
# type tt = {mutable x: int};;
type tt = { mutable x : int; }
# let f = Array.init 10 (fun i -> { x = -1});;
val f : tt array =
  [|{x = -1}; {x = -1}; {x = -1}; {x = -1}; {x = -1}; {x = -1}; {x = -1};
    {x = -1}; {x = -1}; {x = -1}|]
# f.(2).x <- 2;;
- : unit = ()
# f;;
- : tt array =
[|{x = -1}; {x = -1}; {x = 2}; {x = -1}; {x = -1}; {x = -1}; {x = -1};
  {x = -1}; {x = -1}; {x = -1}|]
```

Comment: Actually, most types in OCaml are boxed (are reference types) except `int` and things that can be represented as an int (like `bool`, `char`, and simple enumeration-like data types). e.g. float is boxed; you can see this with `==` (although float arrays are unboxed as a special case). By the way, simple data types like integers and floats are *immutable* by definition since they don't have an internal structure. For an immutable type, there is no difference (other than `==`) if it is a value type or a reference type, so it's generally safe to think of all types in OCaml as reference types.